# Writing a vector to a file and reading it back

Tags: c++, qt, stl, stdvector

I'm trying to do some quick and dirty vector serialization, which doesn't work as expected. The problem is a segfault when trying to read the vector from a file. I store the file offset and vector size in the header. Here's the code:

```
// writing
std::vector<size_t> index;

header.offset = ofs.tellp();
header.size = sizeof(index);
ofs.write((char *) &index[0], sizeof(index)); // pretty bad right, but seems to work   

// reading
std::vector<size_t> index;
index.resize(header.numElements)

ifs.seekg(header.offset);
// segfault incoming
ifs.read((char *) &index[0], header.size);
```

To be honest I'd surprised if this worked, but I'm not sure what is a proper way to achieve what I want. I'd prefer to stay away from boost, but I'm already using Qt so if QVector or QByteArray would help me somehow I could use these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` doesn't do what you think it does for the `vector`. If you want to get the size, in bytes, of the allocated memory for the vector, you can do `index.size() * sizeof(size_t)`. `index.size()` is the number of elements in the vector, and `sizeof(size_t)` is the size of one element in the vector.

The corrected code would be more like (trimming extra stuff):

```
// writing...
std::vector<size_t> index;

size_t numElements = index.size();
size_t numBytes = numElements * sizeof(size_t); // get the size in bytes
ofs.write((char *) &index[0], numBytes);

// reading...
std::vector<size_t> index;
index.resize(numElements);

ifs.read((char *) &index[0], numBytes); // again, numBytes is numElements * sizeof(size_t)
```

As for what `sizeof(index)` really does, it returns the size of the actual vector object. The elements the vector stores are separate from its size. For example:

```
int* array = new int[500];
// sizeof(array) is the size of the pointer, which is likely 4 or 8 bytes if you're on 32 or 64 bit system
```

Comment: That's right, +1, I shoud've checked that. However the problem is still the line that reads the vector.

Comment: @Marian: It shouldn't fail if a) `header.numElements` is right and b) if `header.size` is right. If it's still crashing, one of them is likely wrong. What are there values?

Comment: I've checked with cout that they're set correctly (e.g. 320 for 80 element array). I'll try to run it as separate program and see if that works.

Comment: Ok, it works now. Not sure where the problem was. Just did some small refactoring and somehow the problem is gone. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a pointer to a vector. You are trying to use a reference to a data type. It might not work if your C++ is trying to be typesafe